# Draft.js editor lost focus on Android browser(s) after first word

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using `Draft.js` in a `React.js` project. The Editor works fine on desktop browser(s) (Chrome,Firefox, IE, Edge...) but I have problem in Android device.

After I enter the first word in editor and press spacebar (on soft keyboard) the Editor lost focus & I will have to touch there again if I want to continue to type in the Editor.

This is such a very bad user experience. The `Draft.js` Editor setup is nothing special, just like their example.

Anyone have same problem & have a fix please ?

Comment: `draft-js` team announced that mobile browser is not under support now, but open for github PRs.

Comment: sound great. Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 2):

We got around the problem by [disabling autocorrect](https://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect) for the `contenteditable` div, like so:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  $('.DraftEditor-editorContainer div').attr('autocomplete', 'off').attr('autocorrect', 'off').attr('autocapitalize', 'off')
}
```

There's probably a way to do it without jQuery, but we've already wasted so much time on this problem this was a simple solution. :)

## Update

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/pull/1013) that solves the problem for me. Hopefully other people find it useful. This allowed me to keep autocorrect enabled. I applied the changes in this PR to the v0.10.0 tag of the draft-js repo, NOT `master`.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work in `draft-js@0.10.1`

```
<Editor 
  autoCapitalize={'none'}
  autoComplete={'off'} 
  autoCorrect={'off'} 
  spellCheck={false} ... />
```